# Using AFNetworking to GET public files from S3 and receive 403

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, httprequest, afnetworking

I am trying to download PDF files from our S3 storage. The files are public, and can be accessed through a browser.

When using AFNetworking I receive a 403. The code looks like this

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.pdfUrl]];

void (^success)(AFHTTPRequestOperation*, id) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"WE HAS SUCCESS :D");
};

void (^failure)(AFHTTPRequestOperation*, id) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"failure :((. OPERATION:\n\n%@ \n\nResponseObject:\n\n%@",operation,responseObject);
};

NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"" parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[TTConstants temporaryFilePath] append:NO];

[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Resulting in the outputs:

```
failure :((. OPERATION:
<AFHTTPRequestOperation: 0x95a2f40, state: isFinished, cancelled: NO request: 
<NSMutableURLRequest https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.turtletail.java-bucket/dbda2ccb-91db-4672-9ad4-288dd313ef8c/pdfnumberone.pdf/>,
response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa692480>> 

ResponseObject:

Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 403"
UserInfo=0xa6bda40 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.turtletail.java-bucket/dbda2ccb-91db-4672-9ad4-288dd313ef8c/pdfnumberone.pdf/>,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.turtletail.java-bucket/dbda2ccb-91db-4672-9ad4-288dd313ef8c/pdfnumberone.pdf/,
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 403,
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa692480>}
```

Suggestions would be super!

Comment: I can't actually view the file in a browser. Are you sure it's as available as you think?

Comment: Yes, I changed the name of the PDF for SO. Maybe should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the full PDF URL as the `baseURL` of the `AFHTTPClient` as this results in the final URL having an extra `/` at the end. Instead, set the `baseURL` to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.turtletail.java-bucket/dbda2ccb-91db-4672-9ad4-288dd313ef8c` and then in the request set the path to `pdfnumberone.pdf`.